# How do I save a field in a model without persisting it in db?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm very new to Spring Boot so this is probably a n00b question.

I'm trying to save a field (table number) that is only accessible if a user is logged in. I do not want to persist this in the database.

flow:
- log in
- select table 
- save table number for current user
- do stuff that needs the table number
- log out
- forget table number.

I tried using @Transactional to prevent saving the field and using the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication to get the current user.
Doing this I can save the field. If I later use the same way of getting the current user and calling the getTableNumber() method the field is not set anymore.

I realise this is probably a very simple thing to do, but I'm having some problems understanding how to access models without accessing my database.

If more explanation or actual code is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one **SessionScoped** bean can solve your problem but just for a number value, creating alltogether a bean may not be feasible solution.
So you can store this value in user **http session** and in your controller method you will get that session object. Once you get table number from front-end (as I understood), put it in user http session, use it wherever you want to use by getting it form session object in controller handler method and when the user session is destroyed, the data which is table number in you case will get destroyed automatically.

Now if you want to put this in **model class** also, then you go with **@Transient annotation**, with which persistent layer understand that it should not be persisted in database

Refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/SessionScope.html